# Generating list of neighbors of a state

Tags: haskell

I'm generating neighbours of a state in Haskell.

A state is a list of rows. The actions can be performed independently on a row. A function is called on each row which returns a set of neighbours for that row.

Here's an example (I'll let the rows be chars for simplicity):

```
state = ['a', 'b', 'c']
rowNeighbours a = ['x', 'y']
rowNeighbours c = ['p', 'q']
rowNeighbours _ = []
```

`neighbours` should call `rowNeighbours` on each row and generate a list of states `[['x', 'b', 'c'], ['y', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'p'], ['a', 'b', 'q']]`.

I'm having trouble generating this list. The following is what I came up with as a solution.

```
neighbours state =
[ [x, y, z] | x <- rowNeighbours (state !! 0), y <- [state !! 1], z <- [state !! 2] ] ++
[ [x, y, z] | x <- [state !! 0], y <- rowNeighbours (state !! 1), z <- [state !! 2] ] ++
[ [x, y, z] | x <- [state !! 0], y <- [state !! 1], z <- rowNeighbours (state !! 2) ]
```

It works, but my actual problem has '6' rows, so this becomes quite inelegant and looks like a non-functional way to do things. I would appreciate any pointers on how to go about doing this, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this'll do what you want:

```
neighbors (s:tate) = map (: tate) (rowNeighbors s) ++ map (s :) (neighbors tate)
neighbors [] = []
```